# Octopress Issue - Categories with spaces in them

Tags: ruby, jekyll, octopress

I have categories with spaces in them. I add them in a post as follows:

```
layout: post
title: "Visualizing the Magnitude of Earthquakes in New Zealand"
date: 2012-11-06 19:19:41 -0800
categories: [Data Visualization with R]
comments: true
```

Octopress correctly generates the path `data-visualization-with-r` and when I go to mysite.com/categories/data-visualization-with-r all is well.

However, on the automatically generated 'categories' page the link is to:

mysite.com/categories/data%20visualization%20with%20r/

which is empty.

Does anybody have experience in categories with spaces in them?

Edit: I will add that the link to the category from the main `blog` page is also correct. The only place where it has spaces and is wrong/different is on the /categories page.

Answer (score 0):

how is it automatically generating the categories page? you can use slugify http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/

```
{{ page.categories | slugify }}
```